# How can i split 1 row into multiply rows in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to split something like this:

```
Value |  Startdate  |  Enddate
XXXX  |  2.July     |  16 August
```

Into this:

```
Value |  Startdate  |  Enddate
XXXX  |  2.July     |  31 July 
XXXX  |  1.August   |  16 August
```

The value is not important for now.

Comment: Your need a `cross join`, although exactly what would require more clarity in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to split your range into different months.  A convenient method uses `generate_series()`:

```
select value, greatest(startdate, gs.mon), least(enddate, gs.mon + interval '1 month - 1 day')
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(date_trunc('month', startdate), date_trunc('month', enddate), interval '1 month'
                    ) gs(mon)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e5895f04ba8fb30472aec7dae562abf8) is a db<>fiddle.